# Probability: Defective items in a batch

Tags: probability

A shipment of 10 items has 2 defectives and 8 non-defective items. In the inspection of the shipment, a sample of items will be selected and tested. If a selected item is found, the shipment of 10 items will be rejected.

If a sample of 4 items is selected, what is the probability that the sample contains 2 defectives?

This was a question asked on one of my tests, and I was counted correct for it, but I feel like I got it incorrect. My work was as follows:

> P(Y=2) = (8C2 * 2C0) / (10C4) = .1333

Could someone check my work on this? Why would we do 8C2 non-defective and 2C0? Is this because we are trying to get 2 successes out of 8 possible successes and following the (N-r)C(n-y) format for the number of failures? I think I just confuse myself with all of the subtracting and stuff.

Comment: You obtained the correct answer since $\binom{2}{2} = \binom{2}{0}$.  However, the reasoning in amathguy's answer is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did not even think about that as I was going over the problem. Thank you so much for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate the probability $2$ of your items are defective in your sample of $4$. If you have $2$ defective items in your sample then you also have $2$ non-defective items in your sample. The number of ways to choose a sample with $2$ items that are defective and $2$ that are non-defective is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{2}$. The total number of ways to choose a sample is $\binom{10}{4}$. So the probability of having both defective items in your sample is:
$$\frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{10}{4}}=.1\overline{33}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this explanation. I am sorry to ask such a simple question.